# Customizing Turtlebot3 - OpenCR tweaks needed

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to customize our TB3 by putting it on a different base, but with all the other parts unmodified. Different base means different spacing between the wheels. What is the easiest (?) way to tell OpenCR about this? We've tried rebuilding the OpenCR code with what looks like the appropriate include file modified.

#### More detail

We found what seemed to be the right include file, https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/blob/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/examples/turtlebot3_burger/turtlebot3_core/turtlebot3_core_config.h#L59, and made the modification.

#### Result

We rebuilt the software but when loading it into the OpenCR things aren't working. In other words. When we load the new software onto the board, it doesn't appear to even come up. We are kind of feeling our way blindfolded.

#### Ask

Does anyone have a link to instructions or a case study where this was successfully done? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287313/customizing-turtlebot3---opencr-tweaks-needed/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

You can set distance between wheel on source code (turtlebot3_core_config.h)

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/blob/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/examples/turtlebot3_burger/turtlebot3_core/turtlebot3_core_config.h#L59

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-04-03**:
please check my revised question? Thanks!